# Python getch() - Multiple character

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am aware that python `getch()` is suitable for detecting single keystrokes.

Is there any method, that I can use the same function for detecting multiple keystrokes.s,

Also, is it possible that the program can be made to wait before it prints out the output.

e.g.: `When I press 'w', the program must wait for another keystroke, 'a', before it prints the output for 'w'. I know this is workaround, but I think, as of now, this should do.`

Sample code:

```
try:
    from msvcrt import getch
    print "I am Here"
except ImportError:
    print "Hi"
    def getch():
    print "I am here!"
        import sys, tty, termios            
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)

        try:
            tty.setraw(fd)
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch
def getchs():
    while True:
        yield getch()
for choice in getchs():  
        if choice == 'w':
            print (80 * '-')
            print ("You have chosen Orange...")
            print ("Here's the nutritional fact of the Orange:")
            print ("'One medium orange contains 1.23 grams of protein, 62 calories and 3.1 grams of dietary fiber.'")
            print (80 * '-')
        elif choice == 'a':
            print (80 * '-')
            print ("You have chosen Banana...")
            print ("Here's the nutritional fact of the Banana:")
            print ( "'One medium banana contains 1.29 grams of protein, 105 calories and 3.1 grams of dietary fiber")
            print (80 * '-')
```

Now this works perfect to detect 'w' and `'a'`

How shall I incorporate the feature to have combination: `'wa'`, using the `getch()`, not `raw_input`

I have searched for this, could not find.

Also, will `curses` module help to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

[pykeylogger](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pykeylogger/index.php?title=Main_Page) might help you. As per pykeylogger docs

> It is currently available for Windows (NT/2000 and up), and Linux
>   (using Xlib, so won't work on the console).

For windows only check [keyboard hooks](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=PyHook_Tutorial#Keyboard_Hooks) in [pyhook](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Comment: Most Welcome. I have updated the answer. Please check.